# How to login user in Rails 4 API via ajax with Angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to login an user using Angular instead of regular login (which works atm). Here's my `authenticate` method:

```
def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    User.find_by(:auth_token => token)
  end
end
```

Here's my controller:

```
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     sign_in user
     user.update_attribute(:last_login, DateTime.now)
  if user.admin?
    redirect_to admin_path
  else
    redirect_to user
  end
  else
    redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Invalid email/password combination"
  end
```

This works fine with a Rails based login (no Angular or Ajax).

Now, when I try to implement Angular login (basic for the moment):

```
$http.post('/api/signin', $scope.user).success(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I get the error `Invalid email/password combination`. I'm assuming is to with `CSRF` token, which is not passed via Angular `$http` but I'm using `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` in the sessions controller.

Other point that is I haven't added `csrf_meta_tags` in my Angular html. Would I need to? And how would it render if the html is not served by rails?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide lines from log/development.log (or log/production.log), related to this request from Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you return a json from rails, saying if user is authenticated, then check this on angular

```
# rails controller
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
 sign_in user
 user.update_attribute(:last_login, DateTime.now)
 render json: user
else
 render json: { error: "Invalid email/password combination" }
end

# angular
$http.post('/api/signin', $scope.user).success(function (data) {
  if (data.error) {
   // invalid login
  } else {
   // logged in
  }
});
```

something like that. Any `redirect_to` wouldn't work because you are nothing rendering html from rails.